# Select many items from dropbox & let them appear in a text box

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I want to add the selected items in a drop down box and put them in a text box. 
I can now select just one item & put it in the text box :

Html code:

```
   <select name="ncontacts" id = "contacts" multiple="yes" onclick="ChooseContact(this)"> </select>
```

JS code:

```
    function ChooseContact(data)
    {
      document.getElementById ("friendName").value = data.value;
    }
```

But when I select 2 items just the first one is written in the textbox.
So, do you know how can I fix it, to let both of them appear in the textbox?

Comment: Could you explain your problem further please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible (basic) solution is something like this:

```
function ChooseContacts(selectElem) {
    var txtBox = document.getElementById ("friendName");
    txtBox.value = '';
    for (var i=0; i<selectElem.options.length; i++) {
        if (selectElem.options[i].selected) {
            txtBox.value += selectElem.options[i].value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById ("friendName")` should be stored in a local variable, you do not need to select it from the DOM twice. as well, the length of the options should be cached.

Comment: And you have created a new globabl variable... `i` - should be `for( var i=0`

Comment: @rlemon: The PHP Quiz was yesterday, and orourkek has won it. The question and answer here is merely unrelated to the bounty given, it's more that a specific person has given an answer and that's why there is a bounty. Just in case. But I appreciate that this question benefits from it as well.

Comment: @hakre an incorrect answer still needs updating. this question is still in the collective pool and someone may think that this is the way to do it.

Comment: @rlemon: Sure, as written, there is a benefit. Thanks for your comments, just didn't want to create a wrong impression or something because of the bounty, that's all.

Comment: @rlemon edited/corrected for clarity, good spot of the missing `var` :]

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution is:

```
function ChooseContact(list) {
    var selected = [];
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(list.options, function(option) {
        if( option.selected ) {
            selected.push(option.value);
        }     
    });
    document.getElementById('friends').value = selected.join(', ');
}​
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/AR7b8/)

edit: for the record -
`Array.prototype` is slightly faster than `[]` in execution. But they do the same thing :) The performance penalty is not that much (I use `[]` in my code. but I may as well show you the slightly faster more verbose way).

Answer (score 2):

```
function chooseContact(fromElem, appendToElem, separator){
    separator = separator|| " ";
    var result = [];
    [].forEach.call(fromElem.options, functon(option){
            if(option.checked){
                    result.push(option.value);
            }
    });
    appendToElem.value = result.join(separator);
}
```

Comment: forEach does not work on nodeLists... which is why it didn't work for you. Furthermore, you should cache the length of the options and not calculate them on each iteration.  `for(var i = 0, l = fromElem.options.length; i < l;`

Comment: @rlemon Thanks. Is caching always preferred? Is there no optimization done for that when it's being intepreted?

Comment: no each iteration the array length is rechecked. if you are altering the values of the array (removing or adding) this will screw you up. If you are not there is a slight performance penalty (more if your loop is massive... which it shouldn't be)

Comment: @rlemon Okay thanks. I seemed to remember languages being able to determine that it is a loop invariant, as I am not modifying what i'm iterating over, and i therefore thought it would do that for me.